# Implement this as Attribute or Entity Set?

Tags: database-theory, databases

I am creating a database on students' interests using the Entity-Relationship Model for a University assignment.

Should I implement the circled stuff as attribute, or an entity set?
[image: ER Diagram for Student Interest Database]

Comment: I believe rectangles represent entities in ER diagrams.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But my query is whether to implement it as a multi-valued attribute or an entity set. Kind of seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: It is arbitrary, there is no wrong or right way as long as you are following the normalisation procedures. Only you know what kind of relationships exist between entities and how to implement them

Comment: A note, ER diagram necessarily doesn't translate to an efficient database implementation, details of which are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I know about Normal Forms, but my goal is not to make the most efficient database implementation. I just want to show my professor that I did some work.